# Unpivot T-sql Query

Tags: t-sql, pivot, unpivot

following is the result of my query

```
Year_Month.........cat1_per......cat2_per........cat3_per......cat4_per
2004_06...............0.892..........0.778............0.467..........0.871
2005_10...............0.790..........0.629............0.581..........0.978
```

but i want output of my query to be

```
Category...........2004_06..............2005_10
cat1_per.............0.892..................0.790
cat2_per.............0.778..................0.629
cat3_per.............0.467..................0.581
cat4_per.............0.871..................0.978
```

what is the best way to do it? any help is appreciated.
I tried Unpivot but was not able to get desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the RDBMS but since you tagged it [tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql) I am guessing sql-server.  This is actually both an `UNPIVOT` and then a `PIVOT`.  If you know the values that you need to transform, then you can hard-code them via a static version:

```
select *
from
(
  select year_month, value, category
  from table1
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for category in (cat1_per, cat2_per, cat3_per, cat4_per)
  ) un
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for year_month in ([2004_06], [2005_10])
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c93d6/8)

If you then have a unknown number of values to transform, then you can use a dynamic sql pivot:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Table1') and
               C.name like 'cat%per'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(t.year_month)
                    from Table1 t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select year_month, value, category
        from table1
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for category in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) un
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for year_month in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c93d6/9)

Both will produce the same results:

```
| CATEGORY | 2004_06 | 2005_10 |
--------------------------------
| cat1_per |   0.892 |    0.79 |
| cat2_per |   0.778 |   0.629 |
| cat3_per |   0.467 |   0.581 |
| cat4_per |   0.871 |   0.978 |
```

If for some reason, you did not have the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` functions then you can replicate this using a combination of `UNION ALL` to unpivot and then a `CASE` statement and an aggregate function to pivot:

```
select category,
  max(case when year_month = '2004_06' then value end) [2004_06],
  max(case when year_month = '2005_10' then value end) [2005_10]
from
(
  select year_month, cat1_per value, 'cat1_per' category
  from table1
  union all
  select year_month, cat2_per value, 'cat2_per' category
  from table1
  union all
  select year_month, cat3_per value, 'cat3_per' category
  from table1
  union all
  select year_month, cat4_per value, 'cat4_per' category
  from table1
) un
group by category
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de708/3)

Comment: Thanks for your Swift response. when i use the first query i get the following error 
 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: @arvindreddy what is the query that you are using?  it appears to be working in my fiddle demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c93d6/8

Comment: @arvindreddy Glad you got it working.  If any of the answers on StackOverflow are helpful, be sure to upvote and/or mark it as accepted via the checkmark on the left.  It helps future visitors and even increases your rep. :)

Comment: the dynamic query (2nd) is not working. any ideas? i tried to run it in the SQL Fiddle also. it dint work.

Comment: @arvindreddy are you getting any errors?  can you post a sql fiddle with the version that is failing?  My version seems to be working -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c93d6/9

Comment: i figured out the issue, it was the stuff for unpivot that was not working for my column names. I have changed the colsUnpivot to collect all the cloumns and it is working good now. Thanks