# SQl query to unviot columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have table with structure as

```
display_order   period_to_date  from_date   thru_date   beginning_market_value  net_flows   net_capital_gain    net_income  ending_market_value net_invested_capital    inv_progress
1   MTD 03/31/2015  04/30/2015  36812682.75 -758103.94  139045.6376 51236.84278 36244861.29 36054578.81 190282.4803
2   QTD 03/31/2015  04/30/2015  36812682.75 -758103.94  139045.6376 51236.84278 36244861.29 36054578.81 190282.4803
3   YTD 12/31/2014  04/30/2015  36943568.78 -1508486.51 558539.325  251239.695  36244861.29 35435082.27 809779.02
4   INCP    05/09/2002  04/30/2015  14760256.05 -4742497.95 16969340.37 9257762.809 36244861.29 10017758.1  26227103.18
```

and I want to show output as

```
               MTD             QTD          YTD   INCP
from_date   03/31/2015  03/31/2015  12/31/2014  05/09/2002
thru_date   04/30/2015  04/30/2015  04/30/2015  04/30/2015
beginning_market_value  36812682.75 36812682.75 36943568.78  14,760,256.05 
net_flows   -758103.94  -758103.94  -1508486.51 -4742497.95
net_capital_gain    139045.6376 139045.6376 558539.325  16969340.37
net_income  51236.84278 51236.84278 251239.695  9257762.809
ending_market_value 36244861.29 36244861.29 36244861.29  36,244,861.29 
net_invested_capital    36054578.81 36054578.81 35435082.27  10,017,758.10 
inv_progress    190282.4803 190282.4803 809779.02    26,227,103.18
```

But i am not able to get this result..query I am using is

```
select category,
  max(case when period_to_date = 'MTD' then value end) [MTD],
  max(case when period_to_date = 'QTD' then value end) [QTD],
  max(case when period_to_date = 'MTD' then value end) [YTD],
  max(case when period_to_date = 'MTD' then value end) [INCP]
from
(
  --select period_to_date, from_date value, 'from_date' category
  --from transtable
  --union all
  --select period_to_date, thru_date value, 'thru_date' category
  --from transtable
  --union all
  select period_to_date, beginning_market_value value, 'beginning_market_value' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, net_flows value, 'net_flows' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, net_capital_gain value, 'net_capital_gain' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, net_income value, 'net_income' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, ending_market_value value, 'ending_market_value' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, net_invested_capital value, 'net_invested_capital' category
  from transtable
  union all
  select period_to_date, inv_progress value, 'inv_progress' category
  from transtable
) un
group by category
```

But its not giving correct result.. Its showing same value for all 4 columns

```
category    MTD QTD YTD INCP
beginning_market_value  36812682.7481145    36812682.7481145    36812682.7481145    36812682.7481145
ending_market_value 36244861.2884538    36244861.2884538    36244861.2884538    36244861.2884538
inv_progress    190282.480339332    190282.480339332    190282.480339332    190282.480339332
net_capital_gain    139045.637561555    139045.637561555    139045.637561555    139045.637561555
net_flows   -758103.939999958   -758103.939999958   -758103.939999958   -758103.939999958
net_income  51236.842777777 51236.842777777 51236.842777777 51236.842777777
net_invested_capital    36054578.8081145    36054578.8081145    36054578.8081145    36054578.8081145
```

How can i achieve desired result ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need where clauses in all your union queries? Seems like you're just returning the same query set many times over

Comment: I just took the reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935311/unpivot-t-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT  CAST(period_to_date         AS VARCHAR(20)) AS period_to_date
        ,CAST(from_date             AS VARCHAR(20)) AS from_date
        ,CAST(thru_date             AS VARCHAR(20)) AS thru_date
        ,CAST(beginning_market_value AS VARCHAR(20))    AS  beginning_market_value
        ,CAST(net_flows             AS VARCHAR(20)) AS net_flows
        ,CAST(net_capital_gain      AS VARCHAR(20)) AS net_capital_gain
        ,CAST(net_income            AS VARCHAR(20)) AS net_income
        ,CAST(ending_market_value   AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ending_market_value
        ,CAST(net_invested_capital  AS VARCHAR(20)) AS net_invested_capital
        ,CAST(inv_progress          AS VARCHAR(20)) AS inv_progress
FROM TableName)T
  UNPIVOT (Vals FOR Category IN (from_date,thru_date,beginning_market_value,net_flows,net_capital_gain
                         ,net_income,ending_market_value,net_invested_capital,inv_progress)
          )up
  PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
         FOR period_to_date IN (MTD, QTD,YTD,INCP)
         )P
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9070/1)